# disabling user input php/html form

Tags: php

I have a HTML form which when the user clicks submit, all information is sent to email via a php script using the POST method. What i want to do is disable all user input after the submit button is clicked or grey out all text box input fields. How can i go about doing this?

the code for the submit button at the moment looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Continue " style="width:200px;height:40px">
```

Comment: What happens when user press submit button? Where does page redirect or you are submitting data by ajax?

Comment: Good question @Deadlock! If you are redirecting the page to a process/success page after the user clicks submit, then you dont need to disable the form. If you are doing it with ajax, you can disable all the input with the attribute disabled

Comment: The information is emailed to myself and the page redirects to a success page yes, to say the form has been submitted. But the initial form is part of an application process for the user in which when he goes back to his user account and goes on the form's page, it should be greyed out or disabled as he has already submitted it. I'm not using ajax, just simple php contact form script.

Comment: Are you using any table or storing the form values?

Comment: the form information is passed through a php page, which validates all the information before emailing it. I am not storing in an sql database if thats what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery : `$("input").prop('disabled', true);`
But in pure Html is not possible without refreshing page !

Edit :
**Javascript :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#yourFormID").submit(function() {
        $("#theInputToDisable").prop('disabled', true);
        //Or to disable all inputs 
        //$(this).children("input").prop('disabled', true);
        //$(this).children("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="yourFormID">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: And to enable it `$("input").prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: is this a permanent disable as in if the user exits and goes onto the page later, it will be disabled? also how will i implement this code when the submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Add below to each HTML input element you want to disabled. Since you have not mentioned I assume that you can use PHP for this.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>
```

If you are using AJAX, when the event is fired, inside particular event

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This only works one time, i want it so every time the user goes onto the page, it will remain disabled.

Comment: then you will have to store data in db and check

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of submit button make all input to disabled

```
$("input").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

without db interaction you can't do this out, have a flag in db table. Set the flag 1 if user submit a form, by default 0. Based on the flag value you can disable the form.

```
if(mailsent_status_of_the_user == 1){
    $status = "disabled='disabled'";
}else{
   $status = "";
}



<input type="submit" value=" Continue " <?php echo $status; ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

Since whether mail has been sent is server side processing, its better if you handle this from server end than from client side like jQuery and javascript :

```
$form_state = ($is_mail_sent)?"":"disabled='disabled'";

<input type="submit" <?php echo $form_state ?> value=" Continue " style="width:200px;height:40px">
```